# Check audio and video codec from base64 video file in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, ffmpeg, base64, moviepy

I'm currently working on a Django project where I need to check the audio and video codec of a base64-encoded video file. To achieve this, I've implemented a function that decodes the base64 string into binary data and then attempts to load the video clip using MoviePy. However, I'm encountering an AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'endswith' when trying to run the code.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```py
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def get_video_codec_info(base64_data):
    # Decode base64 string into binary data
    _format, _file_str = base64_data.split(";base64,")
    binary_data = base64.b64decode(_file_str)

    # Load the video clip using MoviePy
    clip = VideoFileClip(BytesIO(binary_data))

    # Get information about the video codec
    codec_info = {
        'video_codec': clip.video_codec,
        'audio_codec': clip.audio_codec,
    }

    return codec_info
```

The error occurs at the line `clip = VideoFileClip(BytesIO(binary_data))` and it seems related to the use of BytesIO. I've tried to find a solution, but I'm stuck at the moment.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue or alternative approaches to check the audio and video codec of a base64-encoded video file in Django would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering with the `AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'endswith'` is because MoviePy's `VideoFileClip` expects a file path or a URL as its argument, but you're passing a `BytesIO` object. To resolve this issue, you can create a temporary file from the binary data and then provide the path to that temporary file to `VideoFileClip`. Here's an updated version of your code:

```py
import base64
import tempfile
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def get_video_codec_info(base64_data):
    _format, _file_str = base64_data.split(";base64,")
    binary_data = base64.b64decode(_file_str)

    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".mp4")
    temp_file.write(binary_data)
    temp_file.close()

    try:
        clip = VideoFileClip(temp_file.name)

        codec_info = {
            'video_codec': clip.video_codec,
            'audio_codec': clip.audio_codec,
        }
    finally:
        temp_file.unlink(temp_file.name)

    return codec_info
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation and taking into consideration, I've found an alternative solution to the issue. The problem arises from the use of `BytesIO` with `MoviePy` in the original implementation. To address this, I suggest a different approach that involves saving the `base64-decoded` binary data to a temporary file and then using `ffprobe` to gather the video `codec` information.

```py
import base64
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os
import json

def get_video_codec_info(base64_data):
    codec_names = []
    
    # Decode base64 string into binary data
    _, _file_str = base64_data.split(";base64,")
    binary_data = base64.b64decode(_file_str)

    # Save binary data to a temporary file
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
        temp_file.write(binary_data)
        temp_filename = temp_file.name

    try:
        # Run ffmpeg command to get video codec information
        command = ['ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-show_entries', 'stream=codec_name:stream_tags=language', '-of', 'json', temp_filename]
        result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        if result.returncode == 0:
            # Try to parse the JSON output
            data = json.loads(result.stdout)
                
            # Iterate through streams and print information
            for stream in data['streams']:
                codec_names.append(stream.get('codec_name'))

    finally:
        # Clean up: delete the temporary file
        os.remove(temp_filename)
    
    return codec_names
```

This approach uses ffprobe to directly extract codec information from the video file, bypassing the issues encountered with BytesIO and MoviePy. Make sure to have FFmpeg installed on your system, as it is a prerequisite for ffprobe.